# Stability of a Fixed Point Using Lyapunov Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

> Determine the stability of $(0, 0)$ for the system
> $$\dot{x}=y^3+x^2y,$$
> $$\dot{y}=x^3-xy^2.$$

I tried to use Lyapunov function for solving this, but can't find a suitable one. Can anyone give any hints about how to come up with a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The origin is unstable which can be shown with the Chetaev instability theorem.

Let $ q = [x, y]^T $ and $ V(q) = xy $. Trivially, $ V(0) = 0 $ and $ V(q) > 0 $ in the first quadrant. Since $ \dot{V}(q) = x^4 + y^4 > 0 $ for all $ x,y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} $, the origin $ q = 0 $ is unstable from Chetaev instability theorem. Let me state the theorem (see Theorem 4.3 in Hassan K. Khalil, Nonlinear Systems, 3rd Edition)

**Theorem:** *Let $ q = 0 $ be an equilibrium point for $ \dot{q} = f(q) $. Let $ V: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a continuously differentiable function such that $ V(0) = 0 $ and $ V(q_0) > 0 $ for some $ q_0 $ with arbitrarily small $ \Vert q_0 \Vert $. Define a set $ U $ as $ U = \{ q \in B_r ~|~V(x) > 0 \} $ and suppose that $ \dot{V}(q) > 0 $ in $ U $. Then, $ q = 0 $ is unstable.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ahmet!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it was helpful @LeftHand